# How do I create a static member for an object in a namespace in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, static-members, oop

I've simulated a static class variable in Javascript.

```
MyObject.staticVariable = "hello world";

function MyObject() {
    // do something
}

MyObject.prototype.someFunction = function() ...
```

I do not understand why this syntax works because I do not create MyObject explicitly (and how could I and still have a MyObject function?) before I assign the staticVariable property.  But it does work, and I've seen it in many answers to the question along the lines of: how do I simulate a static class variable in Javascript?

How can I achieve this functionality when I declare the MyObject function in a namespace?

```
var Namespace = {};

// Not allowed, and for good reason in my eyes, as NameSpace.MyObject does not exist
Namespace.MyObject.staticVariable = "hello world";

Namespace.MyObject = function() {
    // do something
}

Namespace.MyObject.prototype.someFunction = function() ...
```

Let me know if I can clarify and/or if my thinking is off.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of the current lexical environment.

This means that the function exists before any other code in that environment runs.

```
// This works

MyObject.staticVariable = "hello world";

function MyObject() {
    // do something
}
```

---

```
// This does not

MyObject.staticVariable = "hello world";

var MyObject = function() {
    // do something
}
```

In your `Namespace` example, it's effectively the same as the second example. This means that you'll needs to make sure the function assignment happens first.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations are hoisted, that is, you can use them above their instantiation. However, function *expressions* are not. In your example, you do this:

```
Namespace.MyObject.staticVariable = "hello world";

Namespace.MyObject = function() {
    // do something
}
```

This won't work because `Namespace.MyObject` was not (and cannot be) created as a function declaration. As for simulating the functionality, use a function:

```
function add( prop, val ) {
    Namespace.MyObject[ prop ] = val;
}
```

This will allow you to add properties to the object before you explicitly create them:

```
add( "staticVariable", "Hello World" );

Namespace.MyObject = function() {
    // do something
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what you mean by static class variable?  JavaScript is not the same as Java.

If you want a constant that no client can modify, you can use closures. 
For example:

```
var Namespace = {};
Namespace.MyObject = (function(){
  var staticVariable = "hello world";

  //this will be assigned to "MyObject"
  return {
    someFunction: function() {
       //refer to staticVariable here
       //no client can modify staticVariable directly; 
       //only through the methods you provide
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks.  This provides more information than I need, but I think that it is useful information.  I don't really have any reference language in particular in mind, and I meant to replace class with object.  I'm not yet worried about protecting my objects internals, and it's a little beyond me why anyone would bother with doing so in JavaScript, but we'll see how my thinking evolves.